# Read contents of database, convert to string

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently stuck on how to read the contents of a database and convert them into a string. I have some varchar values in my database, what I want to do is create a PHP file where I list the contents of the database with MySQL select (I know how to do this) then convert them to string so I can then store them as variables to perform additional processes with. I'm not sure how to convert them to string though (even after attempting to research it).

Comment: can you echo your queries?

Comment: replace "list the contents of the database" with "extract the contents!" bad wording on my part

Comment: Welcome to SO sqhelpmurphy. Please post what you've tried so far, if people have to guess what you're doing you probably aren't going to get an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Values returned by `mysql_fetch_array()` are of type **var**. Means that they are of no particular type. You can use them directly as a string. Have a look on this tutorial.

[MySql SELECT Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$objStmt = $this->objDb->prepare("
    SELECT
        t.columnOne,
        t.columnTwo
    FROM
        tblTable AS t
    WHERE
        t.someColumn = 1);
");

$objStmt->execute();
$objStmt->bind_result($strCol1, $strCol2);

while ($objRow = $objStmt->fetch()) {

    /*
     * at this point, the two values can be treated
     * as strings, even if they are numeric
     */

    [...do something with $strCol1 and $strCol2...]
}
```